# Running multiple test suites for different API versions

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I have multiple api versions that need to run separately.  Sometimes api tests will be the same, other times they will be different.

```
@v1 @v2
Scenario: the api is the same for v1 and v2

@v2
Scenario: v2 specific test
```

I am setting the api version for each tag

```
@Before("v1")
public void signupSetup(){
    World.api("v1");
}

@Before("v2")
public void signupSetup(){
    World.api("v2");
}
```

I can configure all @v1 tags to run like this. How do I get the v2 tests to run separately?

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"my.package.cucumber", "cucumber.api.spring"}, tags = {"v1"})
public class CucumberTestV1 {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We are using [QAF-Gherkin-client](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html), where you can [configure](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/creating_configuration_file.html) it using two test nodes.

```
<suite name="AUT Test Automation" verbose="0" parallel="methods">
  <test name="V1 Tests">
        <parameter name="env.resources" value="resources/v1"/> 
        <groups>
            <run>
              <include name="v1"/>
            </run>
        </groups>         
        <classes>
              <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory" />
        </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="V2 Tests">
        <parameter name="env.resources" value="resources/v1"/>          

        ...
  </test>
```